# How to assign a field to map tips?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, maptips

In QGIS 1.8, I cannot find the way to assign a field to 'map tips'. There seems to be no way in 'properties' of the layer to do so.

Answer (score 2):

From Layer Properties, General tab, choose the field you want to use with map tips from the "Display field" drop-down list.

Comment: Thank you! I am enjoying the progam more and more, Menze de Graaf - Utrecht - The Netherlands