# Show images related to features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, actions

Say for example, if there's a point data with old trees, then when you use the identify tool, you can see the photograph of the tree

Or even one level further, the labels displaying these images right away without any clicking needed

I believe the term is file streaming?

Comment: Take a look at this idea, from Nathan Woodrow's blog: https://nathanw.net/2016/02/04/live-svgs/

Comment: related: [How to get image pop ups in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123675/how-to-get-image-pop-ups-in-qgis)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Can be done on identification.

You first need an attribute with the photo paths. Must be full path:

[image]

Then you set the widget of the attribute to **Photo**, through the image properties:

[image]

When you identify a feature, it will pop up an image:

[image]

Although you need to have "Auto open form" ticked on in the identify results, also it must only be identifying the layer with images, so the mode should be "Current Selection" so it will identify the layer selected in the layers panel:

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be a local path? Could it be a URL?

Comment: Can be an URL. But you then need to set the widget to "Web View" instead of Photo.

Comment: You don't have to use the whole file path in the attribute value if you use the External Resource widget type and turn on the Integrated Document Viewer to display an Image. QGIS lets you set it to use a static "default path", or the project path. The latter is dynamic but you do need to specify subdirectories in the field values - so if your project is in C:\Projects and images in C:\Projects\Images then your field value should be \Images\whatever.jpg (maybe missing the first slash, can't remember.)

Comment: What if your path has a space? mine for example is N:\Doc\A\Apple Drive 1.pdf the link tries to open N:\Doc\A\Apple which doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Try adding quotes: "N:\Doc\A\Apple Drive 1.pdf"

Comment: "Then you set the widget of the attribute to Photo, through the image properties:" Not clear how to do that...

Comment: You click on whatever the Edit widget is currently set to, and choose Photo from the list.

Answer (score 8):

This is also possible through layer styling by using a combination of a **Geometry generator** to create rectangular polygon placeholders for the image, and then **Raster Image fill** to insert the images. The raster location property can be data defined, but I haven't tested whether it will work with URL sources.

Example:

Geometry generator expression to convert a point into a rectangle 400 x 220 map units across (matching the photo aspect ratio):

```
bounds(  make_line( 
    translate( $geometry , -200, -110), 
    translate( $geometry , 200, 110)
    )
)
```

[image: Point and rectange]

Now give the rectangle a raster fill of a photo:

[image]

(Using QGIS 2.18.15 x64 on Windows 10)

Comment: Works also with URL resources at least in QGIS 3.12. However, I did not yet figure out how to scale the images if the image aspect ratio varies.

Answer (score 6):

This can also be done using "Map Tips".

1. You have to add the URL to the attribute table like Vesanto did.
2. You go to "Layer Properties" --> "Display", there you switch to html and add something like

   ```
   <img width="150px" src="[% "img_url" %]" />
   ```

Advantage with Map Tips --> no clicking needed!

Answer (score 4):

It works with "Forms" if you have an attribute for your image file.  The pathname can be relative.

In QGIS 3.30.0-'s-Hertogenbosch, I have a points layer with a field for a local filename, and under Layer/Properties/Attributes/ you select the field, and on the RHS panel, set the widget to "Attachment" and further down on the page there's an "Integrated document viewer" that you set to Image.

[image]

Then, within the ID tool, when you select the editing form (top left icon of Identify data panel), the form will show the image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

after much experimentation with the guides provided above i just found a really easy solution to view pictures associatet with points:

Go to symbolization --> Rasterimage--> Datadefined overwrite--> fieldtype Piture-chain-->check the picture-Marker

[image]

Answer (score 1):

sadly there is no such thing yet.

your best option might be to get an image attached through a HTML Annotation. Find this Symbol in QGIS:

[image]

ADD: as @Vesanto showed, it is possible. I didn't know about that, but think it's a great thing they added such a feature to QGIS

Comment: Huh I don't have that icon on my qgis 2.14. Is that a new feature in 2.18?

Comment: I don't think so. It's implemented in Attribute Toolbar and I used some 3 years ago. 

Maybe you also want to checkout the eVIS Plugin, but I don't have any experience with it.

Comment: @Luffydude - The icon is a submenu from the **Text Annotation** icon :)

Comment: @Joseph oh I see, silly me