# Putting photos on point using QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis-3

I need to be able to bring the pictures as points and then be able to click at a certain point and an image pops up.

[image]

I added a column for images label as pic. How can I show that image on the point?

Comment: Thank you, i take a tour, Is photo on widget type change to attachment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the steps you are after can be acccomplished with the identification tool. The following post describes a few options for you: 
[Show images related to features in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237156/show-images-related-to-features-in-qgis)