# Link multiple Photos to Features using ID in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, photos

In QGIS I have a Postgis layer with POIs. Further, I have a folder with images. The name of the images matches a unique identifier in the attribute table.

Is it possible to automatically connect these two datasets and show the images when I open the feature form?

I use QGIS 2.4 on a mac, do GIS but no programming.

I had a look a eVis, Import Photos, but couldn‘t do the job.

*Update*:
eVis works. But: I sometimes have two pictures referring to the same ID. Is there a solutions for that?

Comment: look at this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237156/show-images-related-to-features-in-qgis

Comment: @FranRaga thx! I already saw this, but I think they don't automate the connection. What I am looking for is a tool/snipped which "crawls" through my image folder and chooses the correct image for each feature.