Creating Orthomosaic with GDAL
Platform: Windows 11
1. Aim trying to achieve: I have some very high quality multispectral data (drone multispectral imagery), from which I am trying to create an orthomosaic. My multispectral data consists of .tif files in G band. I need a GeoTIFF orthomosaic which is also georeferenced.
2. Steps followed for georeferencing: First I converted the raw .tif files into georeferenced .tif files with GDAL. The files already had GPS metadata. Below is the gdalinfo for one of the georeferenced .tif file:
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: DJI_20231104164259_0001_MS_G.TIF
Size is 2592, 1944
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],
        AREA["World."],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (77.533600277777794,23.247076472222201)
Pixel Size = (0.000001000000000,-0.000001000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2023:11:04 16:42:59
  TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION=default
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=10.12.05.45
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  77.5336003,  23.2470765) ( 77d32' 0.96"E, 23d14'49.48"N)
Lower Left  (  77.5336003,  23.2451325) ( 77d32' 0.96"E, 23d14'42.48"N)
Upper Right (  77.5361923,  23.2470765) ( 77d32'10.29"E, 23d14'49.48"N)
Lower Right (  77.5361923,  23.2451325) ( 77d32'10.29"E, 23d14'42.48"N)
Center      (  77.5348963,  23.2461045) ( 77d32' 5.63"E, 23d14'45.98"N)
Band 1 Block=2592x1 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray

3. Steps followed for generating orthomosaic: I created a list of .tif files and stored the names in a text file. Then I ran this command:
gdal_merge.py -o mosaic.tif --optfile tiff_list.txt

4. Output: This gave me an output, but not what I wanted. The output orthomosaic was just all the .tif files stack on top of each other, I guess there is no blending of common pixels between them (although all the images have 80% of overlapping).
What else can be done here?
The output:


Are you able to get IMU data (roll, pitch yaw) from the drone or images?

Explain your conversion from raw.tif to georeferenced.tif?  Are you sure you have georeferenced images and not geotagged images?  Is this answer helpful?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/468347/problems-importing-dji-phantom-images-into-qgis/468392#468392

@CaryH If I check the exif metadata (with exiftool), it displays the Gimbal roll, pitch, yaw degrees.

I had used a script with osgeo gdal python bindings, I used SetGeoTransform() and SetProjection() member functions to make it georeferenced (WSG-84). To cross verify the georeferencing, I plotted my tif file to qgis. It was not accurate, I will have to make some changes to it. Maybe that is what causing this issue.

It looks like your images may be spun 180.  Are you using any code to adjust the orientation of the image?

Have you looked at ODM - https://www.opendronemap.org/

@CaryH not explicitly, but that looks like it. And Yes I have used ODM before, but unfortunately it does not support tif files. :(

Guys, I got my output by using ODM (turns out it does support TIFs), but nonetheless I would like to know the GDAL pipeline of converting an aerial captured dataset to an orthomosaic.
