# Getting pictures as popup images on spatial points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

The attached images below show a road route (symbolised as a grey dashed line) and point locations of graffiti markings on public properties - these points are symbolised as a black cross-hair.

I have taken pictures of these graffiti markings and linked their path locations of where the .jpg pictures are stored to the point coordinates (see image below).

It is unclear as to how I can get these images to appear as a popup window upon clicking these points as I'm having difficultly following the steps highlighted in previous posts:

1. [Show images related to features in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237156/show-images-related-to-features-in-qgis)
2. [How to get image pop ups in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123675/how-to-get-image-pop-ups-in-qgis)

Is there a simple way of doing this in the latest version of QGIS (3.2.3)?

[image: Spatial data with paths to pictures]
[image: Point locations]

Comment: What difficulties are you having trying to follow those steps?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the question. Maybe here's the answer: https://nathanw.net/2016/02/04/live-svgs/