# Thumbnail picture in QGIS 3.2

Tags: thumbnail

I'm trying to have a thumbnail displayed and can get it working when using a specific picture path.

I have created a new column in the atribute table [image]

I would like to have this be the image source in the code, but I can't seem to get it to work when putting in the name of the expression instead of a full path to a picture. Is there a way to tell the code to take the value of the table I am missing?

When I hover over a point I get:
[image]

With the following code:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting image pop ups in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123675/getting-image-pop-ups-in-qgis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you used in the HTML MAP Tip Builder is a bit wrong. Please use the following:

```
<div style ="width:400; height:400;"><p>test</p>
<div><img src=[% "Linkk" %] width=300 height=300 /></div>
</div>
```

The remaining div content is working fine:
[image]

Comment: I feel a bit starstruck here. Have been going through https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnQk0NRqCyM&t=246s

a few times and ended up a bit confused. Thank you for the reply and your youtube video.

Comment: this video is using a very old version of QGIS. also check #1 of césar's answer!

Comment: Regards to @Riccardo (you didn't know but I'm kind of a groupy). He teach us all through that great http://www.digital-geography.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your workflow.

1. Correct your filepath: /photos/ isn't the same as /Photos/
2. In the popup info properties just use html (remove all in "Vis udtryk").
3. If that wasn't enough use this html code:

`<b>Source: [% photo %]</b> 
 <br>Image: 
 <br> 
 <img src="[% linkk %]" width=300 height=200 />`

[image]

[image]

It works in QGIS 3 as well (remember to click in the popup icon):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see you have an option for "HTML" which I do not have, I'm using version 3.2

Comment: It worked in QGIS 3.2 as well. I have edited the post with images using the same code. The key is to correct that misspelled filepath.