# Add popup images to polygons

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, image, popup

I am already having a multi polygon layer of plantations in QGIS 3.8. Now I want to see popup images of the plantations when the mouse rolls over or clicks the polygon shapefile.

I have until now taken the following steps:

1. created a new attribute field - "image" for the file path.
2. set Widget type - "Attachment"

   - Storage Mode - "File path"
   - Integrated Document Viewer - Type - "Image", Width- "Auto"/ Height - "Auto"

[image]

I had entered the exact file path also, but when I click the polygon using the "Actions" feature or simply click the "Show Image" link in Attributes table, I am getting an error message as below.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! You probably mixed up three different things. 1. _Attributes form_ - how feature form behave and looks like in attribute table and identify tool - you set this 2. _Actions_ - defined actions, can be applied on features by clicking in map canvas, buttons in attribute table etc. - you try to run this. 3. _Display/Map tips_ - mouse hover behaviour - you mention this. What kind of behaviour you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The *Action* that worked for me in case of images stored with relative path :
Type (if Windows) = "open"

```
[% @project_folder %]/[% "Photo_field" %]
```

For full path, you may need to start it with *file:///*.

For *Display/Map tips* (HTML pop-up), I think this is what you're looking for, follow this thread : [Getting image pop ups in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123675/getting-image-pop-ups-in-qgis)

In my case, I have several pictures (N, W, S, E) per feature. I have created different actions for each of them but it would be more convenient if I could display all of them at once, side by side, with *Display/ Map tips*, so my question may be close to yours. Is it possible ? Also, where is this *"Show image" link in Attributes table* ? Thank you.